# Make SublimeText2 aware of local project

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

I am writing my own classes for a project. Apparently RubyMotion recognises some CocoaTouch classes but if I were to write my own classes, Sublime would not be aware of it. How do I rectify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Sublime for RubyMotion development as well? If so, are you using the RubyMotion completions? That could be why you're seeing CocoaTouch class completions.

Sublime doesn't have a built-in code intelligence engine, so if you write your own classes, it won't know about them.

That said, there are some packages that may provide what you're looking for:

https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel

https://github.com/alienhard/SublimeAllAutocomplete

Comment: So If I were to install the two plugins, would SublimeText 2 know about my own classes?

Comment: I've had mixed results with SublimeCodeIntel. SublimeAllAutocomplete works really well given you have your class files open.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this sublime package : https://github.com/diemer/RubyMotionSublimeCompletions

This can also be installed via Package Control, just type RubyMotion and you'll see it

This tool is fairly good to help you type the long Objective-C names, it is also aware of your own class. Only problem is all the default name & method come before your own class and method (which can be quite annoying sometime)